# Serialize collection without root tag

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api2

I'm attempting to setup a Web API endpoint that has a specific requirement that the XML format be similar to this:

```
<broadcast>
    <name></name>
    <description></description>
    <episode>
        <title></title>
    </episode>
    <episode>
        <title></title>
    </episode>
    ...
</broadcast>
```

My models look like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class broadcast
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<episode> episodes { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class episode
{
    [DataMember]
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the `episode` items get put into a container tag <episodes>. Is there any way to serialize the `episodes` list so that the container tag doesn't appear?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out there is a way to do this, but you must use the `XmlSerializer`. To do this add the following line to to your WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Then add the `[XmlElement]` attribute to any collections you don't have to have a root tag. If you want to have a root tag use `[XmlArray]`. So in my example above:

```
[XmlType]
public class broadcast
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement] // could use [XmlArray] if I want a root tag
    public List episodes { get; set; }
}
[XmlType]
public class episode
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kyle's answer is almost correct. You need `[XmlElement("episode")]` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know removing the root element in a collection type is not possible. This is subject of [Collection Type Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850(v=vs.110).aspx) and even though there are multiple options to alter how collections are serialized using attributes like `CollectionDataContractAttribute` there isn't an option to remove the root for the Serialized collection element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MessageContract instead DataContract. Message contracts describe the structure of SOAP messages sent to and from a service and enable you to inspect and control most of the details in the SOAP header and body:

```
  [MessageContract]
  public class broadcast
  {
      [MessageBodyMember]
      public string name { get; set; }
      [MessageBodyMember]
      public string description { get; set; }
      [MessageBodyMember]
      public List<episode> episodes { get; set; }
    }
```

Here you can find more information and details --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts